# C programmin: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to do this integral calculator in the Simpson's method in C programming, but it comes out with an error: segmentation fault(core dumped). I googled some things about it and tried the gdb debugger, but yet I got nothing.

gdb claims: 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004008f6 in main ()

I'm no expert programmer, I do not understand about pointers and stuff of this sort.

What does this error mean? How can I fix it? What should pay attention on so I can prevent it from happening/finding the error?

Thanks in advance (:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double inta,suma; //value of the integral and a provisory value for it
int a; //a sort of boolean

double expo(double x) //the function to be integrated
{
    return exp(-0.5 * pow(x,2));
}


double integration(double min, double max, int division) //the process of integration
{  
    double step = (max - min)/(pow(2,division)); //define the number of steps
    double fake_a;  
    fake_a = min; //a value thats equal to the minimum
    int counter; // to count how many times the steps have been taken
    counter = 1;
    while(fake_a < max)
    {
        fake_a = fake_a + counter*step; //the first value of a
        if(counter % 2 == 0) //even
        {
            suma = suma + 2*expo(fake_a);
            counter++;
        } 
        else //odd
        {
            suma = suma + 4*expo(fake_a);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    inta = suma + expo(min) + expo(max); //final value of the integral
    counter = 1; //reset counter
    return inta;
}

int main()
{
    int N; //N of columns of matrix_inte
    double matrix_inte[N][2]; //a matrix for the evaluating the integrals
    a = 0; //boolean
    double acc = pow(10,-6); //accuracy
    N = 2; //length of the integral vector
    int n_div; //number of divisions
    double mn = -1.0;
    double mx = 1.0;
    n_div = 10;
    //first values of the matrix
    matrix_inte[1][1] = 0; 
    matrix_inte[2][1]= 1;
    matrix_inte[1][2] = 0;

    while(a=0) //main loop
    {
        for(int i=2;i<=N;i=i+1) //takes the differences of a vector[i] and vecotr[i-1]
        {
            double result;
            result = fabs(matrix_inte[i][1]-matrix_inte[i-1][1]);
            matrix_inte[i][2] = result;
        }

        for(int j = 1;j <= N; j = j + 1)
        { 
            if(matrix_inte[j][2] > acc) //checks if there is any value greater than acc
            {
                n_div = n_div + 10;
                N = N + 1;
                inta = 0;
                suma = 0; //readjusts the variables
                integration(mn,mx,n_div);
                matrix_inte[N][1] = inta; //recalculate the integral
            }                    
            else
            {
                printf("%f ", matrix_inte[j][1]); //shows the value of the integral
                a = 1; //changes the boolean
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The debugger will readily tell you precisely where the crash happens. It might be where you access the third element of an array of 2 elements, even before the loop.

Comment: ...and also `N` is not initialized when you use at `double matrix_inte[N][2];`.

Comment: `int N; double matrix_inte[N][2];` : `N` isn't initialize.

Comment: `while(a=0)` -> `while(a == 0)`

Comment: @chris Debuggers are often misleading when dealing with UB..

Comment: If you are not a programmer (and have no desire to become one), you should not write programs. If you need to do some calculations, choose another means - there is no shortage of applications which are much more suited for your task than C++ language.

Comment: @SergeyA And what if the OP *is* a programmer? :)

Comment: @EugeneSh., OP claims clearly they are not (and the tone of the claims is certain that they have no intention of becoming one).

Comment: @EugeneSh., They're just about the best we've got, though. Nothing can be perfect if there's unpredictable behaviour involved. A static analyzer would be nice if possible, perhaps.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not a programmer, but I wish I was. I'm student of physics and I have this programming class. I understand little about the insides of a program. I wish I knew more. About C, I learned it barely a month ago, so I don't know much.

Answer (score 2):

How about reading to the compiler messages?

```
while(a = 0){ … }
```

is a statement without effect to your loop, because it assigns `a` to have value of `0`, which is no condition check for your loop. You should have probably used the equality comparison operator `while(a == 0){ … }`.
Further on,  `2` is past the end of the array `double matrix_inte[N][2]`.

```
matrix_inte[1][2] = 0;
```

and so is here, yet `N` is never initialized.

```
matrix_inte[i][2] = result;
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: The while thing I understood, it was a mistyping of mine. I didn't understand the others.

Why is 2 past the end of the array? It has N lines and 2 columns, so I thought that matrix_inte[1][2] would mean the first line and second column.

Why is N never initialized? As I said, I'm new in programming and even 'newer' in C programming, I don't understand much of it yet.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If array has two columns, these are indexed as [0] and [1]. An element indexed with [2] would already be a "third column". Variable length arrays are optional in C11, so it might be safer `int N = 2; double matrix_inte[N][2];` and turn on all warnings in the compiler.